# Get size and borders of the Form

Tags: delphi, winapi, window

I'm trying to align my child form after the main form "side by side", but have some difficulties

To reproduce the problem create new VCL application and add one button to the form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm1;
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form);
  Form.BorderStyle := bsSingle;
  Form.Left := Left + Width;
  Form.Top := Top;
  Form.Show;
end;
```

And result:

Windows 7: [image]

Windows 10: [image]

After using `Winapi.DwmApi`:

```
DXR1 := 0;
DXL2 := 0;
if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and DwmCompositionEnabled then begin
  DwmGetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, @R1, SizeOf(R1));
  Winapi.Windows.GetWindowRect(Handle, R2);
  DXR1 := R2.Right - R1.Right;
  DYT1 := R2.Top   - R1.Top;
end;

FormJob.Left := Left + Width - DXR1;
FormJob.Top := Top - DYT1;
FormJob.Show;

if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and DwmCompositionEnabled then begin
  DwmGetWindowAttribute(FormJob.Handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, @R1, SizeOf(R1));
  Winapi.Windows.GetWindowRect(FormJob.Handle, R2);
  DXL2 := R1.Left - R2.Left;
  DYT2 := R2.Top  - R1.Top;
end;
FormJob.Left := FormJob.Left - DXL2;
FormJob.Top := FormJob.Top + DYT2;
```

And now this is completely aligned on both Windows 7 and Windows 10

Windows 7: [image]
Windows 10: [image]

But to do that I need to show the child form first. If I call `DwmGetWindowAttribute` for child (and invisible) form before showing I get the same values as for `GetWindowRect`.It is impossible to get this before showing?

Comment: It's a quirk of DWM that you can't query the frame bounds until the window's been shown. What you can do is use DWMWA_CLOAK to cloak the window before you show it.

Comment: I think this question is missing context about why doesn't the forms align in the first place. A reproduction case would be nice.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, but the first part of code has reproduced the problem, or I need to extend this part?

Comment: I add a second form to a new VCL application. Call the code you displayed from the main form replacing FormJob with Form2 and cannot reproduce the issue. The forms align alright. Tested on Wndows 7.

Comment: Possible do you have disabled themes? Also, try to set up your Form2.BorderStyle := bsSingle; Windows with different styles have different values of the shadow width and height.

Comment: I have Aero enabled. Now tested with bsSingle, and also with the modified code in the question, no repro. Did you try this yourself in a *brand new* project?

Comment: Sure, my updated code for reproducing is created with a new project, but Win10 only here and provide code works like on screenshots for Win10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205884/discussion-between-alex-egorov-and-sertac-akyuz).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to comment of **Jonathan Potter** now I have such code and it works:

```
var
  R1, R2: TRect;
  DXR1, DXL2, DYT1, DYT2: Integer;
  bCloak: BOOL; // Can't use Boolean here
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TFormJob, FormJob);
  if (Win32MajorVersion >= 6) and DwmCompositionEnabled then begin
    DXR1 := 0;
    DXL2 := 0;
    DYT1 := 0;
    DYT2 := 0;

    if (DwmGetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, @R1, SizeOf(R1)) = S_OK) and
       Winapi.Windows.GetWindowRect(Handle, R2) then begin
      DXR1 := R2.Right - R1.Right; // Right width of the shadow for parent
      DYT1 := R2.Top   - R1.Top;   // Top height of the shadow for parent
    end;

    bCloak := True; // Make form invisible
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(FormJob.Handle, DWMWA_CLOAK, @bCloak, SizeOf(bCloak));
    FormJob.Show; // Draw invisible form

    if (DwmGetWindowAttribute(FormJob.Handle, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, @R1, SizeOf(R1)) = S_OK) and
       Winapi.Windows.GetWindowRect(FormJob.Handle, R2) then begin
      DXL2 := R1.Left - R2.Left; // Left width of the shadow for child
      DYT2 := R2.Top  - R1.Top;  // Top height of the shadow for child
    end;

    FormJob.Left := Left + Width  - DXR1 - DXL2;
    FormJob.Top := Top - DYT1 + DYT2;

    bCloak := False; // Make form visible
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(FormJob.Handle, DWMWA_CLOAK, @bCloak, SizeOf(bCloak));
  end
  else begin
    FormJob.Left := Left + Width;
    if FormJob.Left + FormJob.Width > Screen.DesktopRect.Right then
      FormJob.Left := Screen.DesktopRect.Right - FormJob.Width;
    FormJob.Top := Top;
    FormJob.Show;
  end;
```

Actually this code less readable and contain the same as original code, but this can help in the future when it is will be necessary to draw custom drawing form.